# Use of different classes based on a single value

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I'm developing an application that should use different class types based on a single piece of information. To better illustrate my question, let me give an example:

suppose `INFO` is a boolean value. Based on its value, my code must use either instances of some class `A`, or some class `B`. Note that for every `A`, `B` is its subclass. `INFO` is set when the application starts and it's not changed throughout the app lifecycle.

My question: *what's the most optimal way to implement this*?

Here are some approaches I've come up with, but feel free to suggest others:

**1. Factory class with methods:**

```
public static A getA(final boolean INFO) {
    return INFO ? new A() : new B();
}
```

**2. Wrapper classes:**

```
class WrapperForSomeClass {

    public final A instance;

    public WrapperForSomeClass(final boolean INFO) {
        instance = INFO ? new A() : new B();
    }

}
```

**3. Interface + Factory class:**

```
public interface IWrappable<T> {
    T get(final boolean INFO);
}

private static final IWrappable<A> WRAPPER_FOR_A = new IWrappable<A>() {
    public A get(final boolean INFO) {
        return INFO ? new A() : new B();
    }
};

public static A getA(final boolean INFO) {
    return WRAPPER_FOR_A.get(INFO);
}
```

If I had to choose, I'd go with no.3. What say ye?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 is shortest and cleanest. Place this method into A class, in order not to create redundant factory class.

Why you'd go for 3? It does the same, but with a lot more code.

Comment: The reason I'd choose option 3 is because it gives me a (false?) sense of flexibility and generality. As for placing the factory method in class A: 1 - I cannot access the source; 2 - I have about 20 similar methods to implement, I think I'd be better of using a Factory class, just for the compactness, if not for anything else. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: If no access to source then factory is the only option. Then, since interface to 1 is the same as to 3, it's safe to implement 1 first and then refactor to 3 when it is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

```
class A
{
}

class B extends A
{
}

class AFactory
{
    public A getInstance(boolean info) 
    {
        return info ? new A() : new B();
    }
}

class MyMainLauncher
{
    private AFactory aFactory;
    private A instance;

    {
        // has access to the boolean value `info`.
        instance = aFactory.getInstance(info);
    }
}
```